# FFMpeg: Take Certain Amount of Screenshots Between X and X?

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, screenshot

Is there any way to get ffmpeg to take X number of screenshots between X time and X time? The way I'm doing my command line code now is like this:

> ffmpeg -ss 79 -i 1.avi -r 1/2.15 -f image2 1_%%05d.jpg

This method only starts taking screenshots starting at 79 seconds, but I can't figure out a way to set an ending time (before the video ends).

Also, I will be displaying these video screenshots on a website and want there to be the same amount of screenshots per video file for consistency purposes. Is there a way to set how many screenshots I want from a video? As in, ffmpeg figures out how much time is between the two points I specify, then figures out how often to take a screenshot based on how many I want total from a video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `-vframes` option to control, how many frames of input `ffmpeg` should work with.

There is also a `-t` option to control, how many seconds of content to process.

Use any one of them.